# Is there a correct way for maintaining data integrity across multiple sql servers?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key-relationship, composite-primary-key

I need to set up a table with two unique, not null fields. PART_ID and RESOURCE_ID. Ideally, the values in these fields will be **a portion** of the contents of two different PK columns, (PART.ID and RESOURCE.ID), residing on a completely different server.  Unfortunately it has to be like that.

From what I have read, Foreign keys are only an option on local tables. Also, as I mentioned I only want a portion of the fields in those tables.  Currently, I don't know of a better solution then creating composite primary key on the new server without any data integrity between the two. I was hoping there was some workaround for maintaining data integrity across servers.  Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Dan

Comment: Nope. You cannot enforce data integrity across databases.

Comment: I didn't think so. Just making sure.

Comment: I think you can come close using [instead of triggers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx) and linked servers...but only on new data.

Comment: bear in mind that servers can be unavailable, databases can be independently restored and that FKs involve checks in both directions - it's not really worth trying to do this because you'll end up with both databases being less reliable overall (each is now "available" only when, in fact, both are available).